# Date formating using zoo in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am working with a time series dataset in which i have months in mmm (e.g jan) format i want to convert them into mm (e.g 01).
my data looks like

```
X            y
jan 1986    45
feb 1986    60



 data %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  select(-X1) %>%
  separate(X,c("months","years")) %>%
  mutate(months=replace(months,months=="fab","feb")) %>%
  mutate(months =format(months,"%m",justify = "left",trim=TRUE))
```

when i run the above command i get the error.

```
`Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  invalid 'digits' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In format.default(c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "july",  :
  NAs introduced by coercion`
```

I am using `dplyr` and `zoo` package for this.

Comment: thanks Joel for your reply it is not working as expected. It attaches arbitrary days in dates and when i use it dplyr pipeline it gives the error Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes another way to solve this problem in an optimized way is

```
l<-"01"
d<-data %>%
tbl_df() %>%
select(-X1) %>%
separate(X,c("month","year")) %>%
mutate(month=replace(month,month=="fab","feb")) %>%
unite(date,year,month,sep="-") %>%
mutate(date=paste(date,l,sep="-")) %>%
mutate(date=ymd(date))
```

I had used lubridate package here.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for?

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(df$x), format = "%b %Y")
# [1] "1986-01-01" "2001-02-01"

# OR

month(as.yearmon(df$x)) # from data.table package
# [1] 1 2
```

---

this approach might need to have clean data. THere could definitely be better ways.

```
months_list <- c("jan" = 01, "feb" = 02, "mar" = 03, "apr" = 04, "may" = 05,
                 "jun" = 06, "jul" = 07, "aug" = 08, "sep" = 09, "oct" = 10,
                 "nov" = 11, "dec" = 12)

 df %>%
 select(x) %>%
 separate(x,c("months","years")) %>%
 mutate(months=replace(months,months=="fab","feb")) %>%
 mutate(months = months_list[months])
 #  months years
 #1      2  1986
 #2     12  2001
```

Comment: No this is not for which i was looking for i want the code that i can append in above written code to get the data in required format.it is not working in the pipeline. Thanks for your reply

Comment: again giving the error Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  wrong result size (11), expected 372 or 1

Comment: I had also tried to run this code months = months_list[names(months_list) %in% months] separately outside the pipeline by creating same variables of months and months_list but again getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: i think i am using updated versions of all of them as dplyr_0.5.0, tidyr_0.6.1, zoo_1.7.13. They all are updated versions.

Comment: did you try the `months_list` code i edited my answer with? does that too error out at your end?

Comment: @jarryjafery could you try the `months_list` approach again? I have made minor chnages